# The right way perform multithreading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, ios5

I am new to iPhone development, and have been working on an app the last few months off and on as time allows for work.  In particular, I wrote an update function to update the sqlite database on the phone with data from our online mysql database.  The update itself worked fine, but it froze the UI until the update was completed.

This really wasn't too big of a deal, but even though the phone app said it was updating (the button stayed the blue color of being pressed down and the text on it changed to "Updating", as well as a text message above it appearing saying it is updating), some people still did not know it was updating...  So, I then wanted to put the update into it's own thread so that I could show that little processing image in the middle of the screen as well (because the image froze too when I put it in without multithreading).

My issue is: I do not know the proper way of starting a thread while "pausing" the application (not letting the user navigate to other pages, etc), then "unpausing" the application upon completion.

I actually have this working, but only in the simulator.  It does not work after we upload to iTunes and download after they approve it.  The application is forever paused.  Here is my current code:

Main thread, which starts the update process:

```
- (IBAction)update:(id)sender{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doUpdate:) toTarget:[UpdateViewController class] withObject:nil];

    canGo = FALSE;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(threadDone:) name:NSThreadWillExitNotification object:nil];

    while (!canGo){
    }

    [activity stopAnimating];
    activity.hidden = YES;
    status_text.text = @"Update Successful!  You may have to close and restart the app.";
}
```

As you can see here, I create another thread, then have a while loop indefinitely hold all other processes from taking place so the user can't navigate within the program.  (I know this MUST be wrong, but I cannot find an example of the correct way of doing this.)  Previous to this function being called, I start the animation for the processing image.  (And yes, I'm aware that these are not technically "functions" from what I've read, but please excuse the wrong terminology.  Like I said, I'm new.)

Then, in the new thread:

```
+ (void)doUpdate:(id)param{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    // Stuff happens here

    UpdateViewController *talkThread = [[UpdateViewController alloc] init];
    [talkThread threadDone:nil];

    [pool drain];
}
```

And another function being called by both (which works on simulator, but not after iTunes download):

```
-(void)threadDone:(NSNotification*)arg {
    NSLog(@"Exiting");
    canGo = TRUE;
}
```

I've also tried commenting out the code that calls the "threadDone" function and in my new thread, I used:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishLoop) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:FALSE];
```

with a new function that did the exact same thing as threadDone:

```
-(void)finishLoop{
    NSLog(@"Finish Loop");
    canGo = TRUE;
}
```

This didn't do anything at all.  In the debugger, the finishLoop was never called at all as I stepped through the update.  But I get no errors on the "performSelectorOnMainThread" line, so I don't understand what is wrong with that.

So I would greatly appreciate someone explaining the correct way of setting up another thread that will pause the UI without freezing it (so that I can display text such as "hotels have been updated" or what-not as the update takes place, and so the progress image doesn't freeze), and then unpausing the UI after the update completes.  Thank you very much in advance, as this has been a pain for quite a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the user from interacting with the UI, call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]`. When the user is allowed to interact again, call `endIgnoring...`.

EDIT: You asked about how to call something when the thread finishes. This is what a GCD thread architecture looks like:

```
dispatch_async(my_queue, ^{
    // ... do stuff in a background thread ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // ... the thread is over, do stuff on the main thread ...
    });
});
```

It really is that simple.

Comment: This sounds good, but I don't know how to properly call something when the thread finishes.  It seems to work on the simulator, but not after downloading from iTunes.

Comment: Well, step one is don't use all that `detachNewThreadSelector:` stuff. Situations like this are why we are blessed with Grand Central Dispatch. That makes it *very* easy to call something back on the main thread when the thread finishes.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure how to set up the "myqueue" variable, but I set it up like `dispatch_queue_t my_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);`.  I get no errors when entering the first queue, but the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{` never gets entered into.  It doesn't execute the code between that.

Comment: Actually, I really don't need the second one anyway.  Since this keeps all my inner-variables in scope, I can flip my bool variable at the bottom of the first queue.  This seems to work, and I will release this on iTunes and see if it continues to work and let you know.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know if you've answered my question yet.  I do indeed test on my own device first.  As I said in the previous comment, this seems to work.  However, as I found out previously (which is what prompted this thread), just because it works when building directly to my iPhone, it does not mean it will work after iTunes gets a hold of it.  So I do not know if this does indeed work until after apple approves it and I download it from iTunes, which is when I'll respond accordingly.  But no worries, if it works, I will accept this as the answer.  Thanks~

Comment: Well, that's not what you said in your original question. You said: "I actually have this working, but only in the simulator. It does not work after we upload to iTunes and download after they approve it." There's a step missing there - Simulator and iTunes, but no testing on device. You have not used the word device _anywhere_ except in your preceding comment. Testing on the device should be decisive; if you do this right, the binary you test with is _identical_ to the binary that users download. Apple does not change it, as you seem to imply.

Comment: I don't know what apple does to it, but really, neither do you.  Whatever they use to compile it could indeed be different than xCode.  Not that there's a reason for it to be, but as it does work on my phone when I build directly to it and not when I build it for archive and upload it to iTunes, something is obviously going on.  It could even be a difference in building for development and deployment.  Either way, I can't know until it's downloaded from iTunes.

Comment: "It could even be a difference in building for development and deployment." Then do an ad hoc deployment build and run that on your device. You've said you're new to iPhone development. So presumably you want to learn. Then learn this: Apple does not change your binary. The binary you send is the binary they distribute. They don't "compile it". They can't. They don't have the code. *You* compile it. And if you build and archive, the binary from that archive is absolutely the same every time.

Comment: Yes, I do want to learn.  And I thought they had to compile it because when I could actually see the build files before this latest version of xcode, it looked like it was just a zip file of my files.  But that's good to know.  I'll have to look up how to do the ad hoc deployment build.

Comment: Well, I found out how to set up the Ad Hoc build and finally got it to where the app installs that way.  However, after I ran it like this, the update still did not know when the background process had completed.  Right now, I just flip my bool variable at the bottom of the update process in the queue.  Worked on my phone with the debug build, but not Ad Hoc.

Comment: I didn't think of it before, and was still trying to use my loop with this type of multithreading (if that's what this is called).  But I used your first method for stopping all user interaction along with your queue, and it seems to be working.  This will work, and I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the user from going anywhere while you're working in the background, you should either set the enabled property on each UIControl (UIButton, UITextField, etc), or perhaps overlay a transparent UIView over the whole UI to block touch events.  Infinite loops are never the right answer. The effect of using them will defeat the purpose of using a background thread.  If there are specific user actions you're not sure how to block during the update, post in the comments and we can figure it out.

Comment: Well I don't want the user to be able to do anything at all.  The UI freeze was actually just fine with me.  But now that I need to put that animated image up to show that the update is in progress, I can't have the UI freeze anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) and save you some work.
This thing would fit exactly your needs. Displaying a process indicator while doing some work in the background.

Comment: But would it really be necessary to include a complete class just to flip a flag in the code?  I don't need any extra notifications, just want to know when the thread exits.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD#readme) framework ? It is open source and seems to meet what you are looking for.

[MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD#readme) is an iPhone drop-in class that displays a translucent HUD with a progress indicator and some optional labels while work is being done in a background thread. The HUD is meant as a replacement for the undocumented, private UIKit UIProgressHUD with some additional features.